# Apache Tika Parsers error for old MS document formats

Tags: java, maven, apache-tika

We use Apache Tika Parsers for document validation and after updating to version 2.3.0 our regression tests are failing for older MS document types (ppt, doc, pub, etc.) with the following error thrown by `tika.detect()`: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WORKBOOK_DIR_ENTRY_NAMES`.

It is true that these document types are old, but they can still be opened with their corresponding apps, so I believe they should be properly validated by Tika Parsers.

Comment: Looks like you have an old copy of Apache POI on your classpath (a Tika dependency) - how are you including Tika in your project?

Comment: I updated to latest version of Apache POI, but the error is still there..We just include both Tika and Apache POI as Maven dependencies.

Comment: You'll need to check your classpath for older copies of POI, sounds like you have two copies by accident. https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html has some code you can use to see what jars you are really using

Comment: I double-checked the entire dependency tree and only tika-parsers 2.3.0 and apache-poi 5.2.2 are there. In case you are one of the contributors of tika, I added the offending files here, in case you'd like to have a look: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9106f08b5345542e25e25179f88247f920220401154628/bd0f01c2a1f07aa24b02e0b789ffe2e520220401154641/273e62

Comment: If you can create a small standalone project which shows the issue, create a Tika jira